# Boost PFC power loss calcaulation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, power-factor-correction, rms

I am studying boost PFC topologies.
I run into a question, how to calculate the CCM / CRM /DCM boost PFC power loss.
I read the On semi document. I would like to derive the Diodes RMS current, but I don't know how to start, does anyone try to derive it? I search for many documents, but no document talking about how to derive it, only give me the result.
Cam someone teaches me how to do it? or any book I could read to get more detail on power loss?

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/tnd6278-d.pdf

[image]

Comment: The rms current is usually not necessary for determining the loss in the diode unless the ac ripple is extremely high. The loss in the diode for a boost converter is \$\approx V_fI_{out}\$ and that is the reason why the diode rms current is seldom derived.

Comment: Diode losses are often ignored as long as the diode Current rating is close to  the FET, but the square law makes it hard to choose the Vf as it rises alot with burst current due to bulk resistance which depends on the power rating of the diode and wide tolerances or current rating of the Si Diode.  A FET doesn't have the intrinsic voltage drop of the diode, thus diode losses can be higher

Comment: @VerbalKint May I know how to derive the equation? do you know that

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I don't need to consider it?

Comment: You always need to consider the power and speed choice of diodes but average current and rms only diverge greatly with ripple in DCM, so he suggested DC average is close enough. I cant say.

Comment: The conduction loss of a diode is \$P_d=I_{d,rms}^2r_d+I_{d,avg}V_{T0}\$. In this expression, \$r_d\$ represents the diode dynamic resistance at the operating current while \$V_{T0}\$ depends on the technology (0.4 V for Schottky and 0.65 V for Si). You can, for many applications, use the average current (which is \$I_{out}\$ in a PFC) and the \$V_f\$ at \$I_{out}\$ (see the data-sheet of the diode) to estimate the conduction losses as \$\approx I_{d,avg}I_{out}\$. A temperature measurement later on the bench will confirm (or not) the approximation.